# Is there a standard way to read the Legendre symbol?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is there any standard way to read (in English) the Legendre symbol (a|p) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol), say, similar to "a choose b"
which is used for the binomial coefficients?

Comment: I wouldn't mind knowing how this is read in *other* languages, by the way :)

Comment: I am almost certain that the answer to your question is "no", and for everyone that posts an answer saying "well _I_ say it this way" this is in some sense more evidence that the answer really is "no". Isn't that strange?

Comment: I think Kevin is correct.  (As for myself, I say "the Legendre symbol of a with respect to p", because I don't know what else one is suppose to say.)

Comment: Mariano: In German,(a|b) is read "a nach b", according to a German mathematician who asked me the original question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I say "a on b" for the Legendre/Jacobi/Kronecker symbol.  This works because, as an American, I say "a over b" for an ordinary fraction.

Comment: I don't think I have ever heard anyone in English say anything other than "a on p" for (a|p) when trying to read the symbol.  Perhaps they've said something more involved like "the Legendre symbol with denominator p" for the function (*|p).

Comment: Really?  Everyone says "a on p"?  I think I usually still just say "a over p" for the Legendre symbol (at the board), sometimes prefaced by "the Legendre symbol."

Answer (score 7):

I use "a legendre b" for the Legendre symbol. I know this is probably not very common and a bit idiosyncratic but I think it is quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

I recently started using "QR a b"

Comment: To use this in the statement of quadratic reciprocity, you'd have to talk about QR $p$ $q$ and QR $q$ $p$, which don't sound good to me.  (An issue that came up in my thesis:  If $\ell$ and $p$ are already taken for primes, and $q$ is already taken for a prime *power*, what is the notation for anotheer prime?)